# Link field value is missing from views raw result in views_get_view_result($view->name, $display_id = 'some_display');

Tags: views

I have the link field module enabled and It works fine with views. Except when I get the views result in code using view->execute or views_get_view_result I do not see the link field result. Is the link field handlers invoked during the render phase? If so how can I attache the link field views result to the views result.

Comment: can you give us a dpm() or print_r() of what you are getting?

Comment: I am getting all the expected cck fields values except for the link field that (link module field) which has its own views handler.  I will get a dpm as soon as I get back to the code.